# what should be the xpath or query-parametr in API to use if I want to get the data only if <deleted> = false.?

Tags: xml, rest, xpath, jira-rest-api

This is the REST API: `https://{ip}:{port}/fedsvc/objectstores`.
Below is the REST API response.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Id>objct040</Id>
        <Name>longevity-large</Name>
        <status>Starting</status>
        <deleted>false</deleted>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Id>obs1040</Id>
        <Name>SRS-large</Name>
        <status>Starting</status>
        <deleted>true</deleted>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

What should be the xpath or query-parametr in API to use if I want to get the data only if `<deleted>` = false?

I expect only the below values to be extracted:

```xml
<Id>objct040</Id>
<Name>longevity-large</Name> 
<status>Starting</status>
<deleted>false</deleted>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath:

```
/Objects/Object[deleted='false']/*
```